# Bind two Textboxes to one and the same Checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want to use a checkbox to control 2 textboxes. 
TextboxA is ENABLED on application start, textboxB is INVISIBLE on application start.
If the checkbox is checked, then textboxA should be DISABLED and textboxB should be VISIBLE.

Here is what I tried:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtHv" AcceptsReturn="False" PreviewTextInput="NurFuenfZahlenErlauben" MaxLength="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="Auto" KeyUp="txtHv_KeyUp" Margin="0,0,99,0">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbKeineHv, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value=""></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>

<CheckBox x:Name="cbKeineHv" Content="Keine HV" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,5,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtKeineHv" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="39,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbKeineHv, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">                           
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

If I check the checkbox, however, only textboxA "txtHv" will be disabled while textboxB "txtKeineHv" remains invisible. What am I doing wrong? Why is the second data trigger setter not firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox "txtKeineHv" has local value for Visibility: `Visibility="Hidden"`

Style trigger cannot override it.

Use a Setter for Visibility:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtKeineHv" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="39,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbKeineHv, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">                           
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```